# applying all the missing permissions from folder source to folder target in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, permissions, filesystems, folder-permissions

I know this:

[how to script out all the permissions in a folder using powershell?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/218984/22336)

```
$Acl = Get-Acl "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER01\MSSQL\DATA"
Set-Acl "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\test" $Acl
```

But how, instead of *copying and overwriting* the current permissions on the target folder, just add the complementary permissions?

Something like, copying all permissions from *source* to *target*, but leaving the existent permissions of *target* remain there.

at the end the *target* folder will have all of its previous permissions plus all the permissions on *source* folder.

Comment: Get existing permissions for target, add the new ones, apply the complete set. There's examples out there for this but also there's a PS module available to make these tasks easier. I'll look up the name tomorrow.

Comment: it would be very helpful if you could, please

Answer (score 0):

Get-ACL the permissions from the destination, then add the source permissions to it, then re-apply to the destination

Here's an example to add just a single permission:

```
$NewFolderRule = New-Object  System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("MyDomain\Domain Admins","FullControl","ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit","None","Allow")

$DestinationFilePath = 'c:\temp'

$DestinationACL = Get-ACL $DestinationFilePath
$DestinationACL.AddAccessRule($NewFolderRule)
Set-ACL -Path $DestinationFilePath -AclObject $DestinationACL
```

...however this Powershell module makes life a lot easier and is worth using:

[NTFS Security PS Module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/NTFSSecurity/4.2.6)

Comment: it is too early for me, when I get in the office I will test it and let you know